# Is it safe to set RAM frequency beyond Intel's POR?

Tags: memory, bios, supermicro, frequency

Memory in our SuperMicro servers runs on a somewhat lower frequency than it could and it seems to be artificially limited by the `Enforce POR` BIOS setting. SuperMicro [warns on their website](https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=22237) that "there is no guarantee" if this setting is disabled:

> Soft remind, there is no guarantee for this function, since it's not follow Intel POR.

Unfortunately, I haven't even found what exactly Intel POR (Plan of Record) is.

Is there potentially (and practically) any reliability issue regarding this setting?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there potentially (and practically) any reliability issue regarding this setting?

Yes, you're more likely to have memory stability issues if you run your memory system (memory controller on CPU, memory channels and the DIMMs themselves) outside their approved limits.

On a separate note - it's generally accepted that 'server pro's' never seek to 'overclock' their servers, it's the sign of 'newbie'.